# Google Sheets Java API 3 quota

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gdata

I'm using Java `SpreadsheetService` class from `gdata 1.47.1` and from time to time my service account gets blocked and asked to solve some CAPTCHA. In the block message Google asks me to prove that I'm not a robot and I violated some [terms](http://www.google.com/policies/terms/). This happens usually when I exceeded 18-22 requests from one IP and from one service account per one second.

Does anybody know is there a way to avoid such blocking and/or increase my quota. I found that I can control the quota for Drive API and many others, but still can't get how to control Spreadsheet quota.

**UPDATED**
The interesting moment, that using spreadsheet API doesn't affect to any quota included in Google developer console. For example when I create document it hits to Drive's quota (I can see it in 'Usage quota'), but when I update cells/get worksheets via spreadsheet API it doesn't hit any.

Answer (score 1):

Project quotas can be seen on the Project's developer console page. Typically a project is given

- 1,000,000,000 requests/day
- 1,000 requests/100seconds/user

In which you can add more if necessary (you'll incur charges though). In terms of quota specific to Spreadsheet, I don't think there's any references to that. I'll probably just assume its the same quota the Drive API is using.